# Web Scraping / Proxy Issue in R

Tags: r

I believe I'm having a sort of a proxy or firewall issue here. I'm starting out with webscraping, and currently going through someone else's code that I'm not familiar with.

The code below is scraping some data from a site to mend into a dataframe, but as the website changed, the old code is rendered invalid. On my old post here, @alistaire posted a solution, but there was a time out error (probably due to a proxy/firewall issue). It was suggested to use `httr::GET` for more control, but I'm still having a bit of trouble.

**Previous Code**

```
url = "http://origin.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/ensostuff/ONI_v5.php" 
page <- readLines(url)
ONI_data_raw <- data.table (readHTMLTable(page, which=8))
headers <- c ("Year", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
setnames(ONI_data_raw, headers)
ONI_data_raw = melt(ONI_data_raw, id.vars = "Year")
names(ONI_data_raw)[2] = "Month"
names(ONI_data_raw)[3] = "ONI_Value"
ONI_data_raw$Month = as.numeric(ONI_data_raw$Month)
ONI_data_raw$ONI_Value= as.numeric(ONI_data_raw$ONI_Value)
ONI_data_raw = subset(ONI_data_raw, ONI_data_raw$Year %in% time )
```

**Alternate Routes**

```
getURL("http://origin.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/ensostuff/ONI_v5.php")
[1] "<TITLE>Error</TITLE>\n<BODY>\n<H1>Error</H1>\nFW-1 at fw-ukvpna: Access denied.</BODY>\r\n"

GET("http://origin.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/ensostuff/ONI_v5.php")
Response [http://origin.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/ensostuff/ONI_v5.php]
  Date: 2018-01-22 08:35
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html
  Size: 85 B
<TITLE>Error</TITLE>
<BODY>
<H1>Error</H1>
FW-1 at fw-ukvpna: Access denied.</BODY>
```

End goal: ideally, I would like to get it in a form to make a data.table out of, and continue to use the full portion of the previous code. On the run, but any suggestions appreciated and happy to provide more light.

Comment: do you know the proxy server? you can set the proxy server before calling `httr::GET`

Answer (score 0):

I can `getURL` the page fine from my computer, so likely your issue is outside of the code: some permissions config or something, or maybe the website blacklisted you after enough failed attempts.

If you just want to use the data, I would advise using developer tools in browser, and copy pasting the html for the table into a text file, and then parsing the text file.